# Static array of const pointers to overloaded, templatized member function

Tags: c++, templates

Static array initialization... with const pointers... to overloaded, templatized member functions. Is there a way it can be done (C++03 standard code)? I mean, if I have the template class

```
template <class T1, class U1, typename R1>
class Some_class {
public:
    typedef T1 T;
    typedef U1 U;
    typedef R1 R;

    R operator()(T& v) { /* dereference pointer to a derived class (U),
                            overloaded member function (U::f) */ };

private:
    static R (U::* const pmfi[/* # of overloaded functions in U */])(T&);
};

Used as

template <class BASE, typename RET>
class Other_class : public Some_class<BASE, Other_class<BASE, RET>, RET> {
    RET f(/* type derived from BASE */) {}
    RET f(/* other type derived from BASE */) {}
    RET f(/* another type derived from BASE */) {}
    ...
};

Question: how can I initialize de array pmfi (no typedefs, please)?
```

Notes:
1. As a static array MUST be initialized at file scope, template parameters and pmfi must be full qualified (the only way I know to access template parameters outside a class scope is to typedef them...).
2. So far so good. No problems with the compiler (Comeau 4.3.10.1). Problems start popping up when I try to fullfill the initializer list { ... }.
2.1. The compiler complains the template argument list is missing, no matter what I do.
2.2. I have no idea how to select the correct overloaded U::f function.

BTW, this is a kind of "jump table" generator from a boost.preprocessor list. The code I am trying to implement is of course much more complex then this one, but this is his essence.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `BOOST_PP_ENUM` in the way that you've shown, you would need a macro that takes a 'number' and yields an expression that is the address of an appropriate member of the appropriate class. I don't see a good way to do this without an explicit list unless the desired functions all have manufactured names (e.g. `memfun1`, `memfun2`, etc.). Except in the case, it's going to be easier to list the function address expressions explicitly that to used BOOST_PP_ENUM.

You are using identifiers in this array that are the same as the template parameters in `Some_class`.

```
R (U::* const pmfi[])(T&) = { /* ... */ }
```

Is this really supposed to be the templated member of Some_class?

```
template< class T, class U, class R >
R (U::* const Some_class<T, U, R>::pmfi[])(T&) = { /* ... */ }
```

If so, is the same instantiation going to work with all combinations of types that you are going to us the template `Some_class` with? If so, you have a very constrained set of classes, perhaps you can do away with the template. If not, you are going to have to specialize `Some_class` for every combination of template parameters in which case the template is not gaining you very much.

**Edit, post edit:** If I've understood you correctly then you can't do what you've suggested because the array of pointers must be of exactly the right signature.

Reducing it to a simple function pointer example, you can't do this:

```
void f(Derived&);

void (*p)(Base&) = &f;
```

otherwise, it would subvert type safety:

```
OtherDerived od; // derived from Base, but no from Derived

 // I've managed to pass something that isn't a Derived reference to f
 // without an explicit (and dangerous) cast
(*p)(od);
```

In your array of function pointers, the initializers must all be to functions of the right signature.

Comment: Hi, Charles
1. Indeed, I use a "seq" from boost.preprocessor to expand `BOOST_PP_ENUM` and to generate a typelist (used in the process)
2. Those are not real code. The identifiers in the code should be meant as typedefs of the template args

If R, T, U are typedefs of template args of Some_class (forget the rest), array definition would be

Some_class::R (Some_class::U::* const Some_class::pmfi[])(Some_class::T&) = { ... };

Q: which should be the sintax of the ... part?
A: &Some_class::U::f (wich overloaded f?)

If U is itself a template, how to say that?

Comeau does not agree with my tries

Comment: I mean U is a template parameter of Some_class, but if U represents a class template, how the address of the function U::f should be written? &U<P1, P2...>::f? How to select the right overloaded f? You got it. BTW, even for a 1 elem array (so no overload) comeau compiler does not accept the above sintax.

Comment: "Those are not real code." Then can you _carefully_ post some real code and describe the problem that you are trying to solve. Your solution looks overly complex, but without knowing what the problem is, it's difficult to say. In particular can you post a sample class that you want to use for the template parameter `U` (or is it `U1` now?) and also where `Types` and the metafunction `Length` are defined? Post edit, you now seem to have an error in the declaration of `Some_class::pmfi`.

Comment: Sorry. I redefined the question (I hope with unneeded information stripped out).

Comment: I was afraid of the answer being the functions signatures. As you can assign an object of a derived class to a base class pointer, I thought a base class pointer could accept the address of a derived member class function. Shame on me! Thanks for spending your time with such a foolish question.